# Mysql errno 150 trying to create table with foreign key references

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, create-table

I'm trying to create a table in mysql with a foreign key reference, like this:

In database A:

```
CREATE TABLE replication (
  id varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  uid varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  value int(11) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES databaseB.users(username)
);
```

In database B i have a table named users like this:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| username        | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

When i try to create table replication, gives me the following error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'databaseA.replication' (errno: 150)
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an index to uid or you will not be able to set it up to reference anything.

Also, typically in your DatabaseB you would have your users table have a Primary Key on ID and a unique index on username. Then you would set up a foreign key from DatabaseA.replication REFERENCES databaseB.users(id)

Answer (score 2):

you cant make reference key with two different types

in databaseA is integer uid and databaseB is varchar

try this

```
  FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES databaseB.users(id)
```

Comment: While true, he was linking to two different types, the real issue that MySQL was complaining about was the fact that he was trying to create a reference on a non-indexed field.

Answer (score 1):

Are both databases of the same type (MyISAM, INNODB)? You cannot point a foreign key to a MyISAM DB.
This error can also occur when you are mixing types for the field type (which is the same in this case, varchar(255)), or when the encodings of the fields are different.
Another reason could be that you don't have access to the other database.

Answer (score 1):

The`type of the field` in a `foreign key` must be the `same` as the `type of the column` they're `referencing`.I think this problem error because type of the field in a foreign key is different from the column they're referencing.
Your foreign key field is `uid` and referencing table your field is `username`.Here is the problem.Try to use `same` type of field in both `table` like

```
 FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES databaseB.users(id)
```

Hope you understand and works for you.